# Azure CI/CD building separate zips for web projects and api

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have 2 web projects and 3 api
I would like to create a pipeline that builds/publishes teach of the 2 web projects and 3 api to separate zips  as part of the artifact

The following dumps all into one zip called `a.zip`, and if i set `publishWebProjects: false` then it only creates 2 zips, one for each web projects and nothing for web api.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2 
  displayName: ".NET Core 7"
  inputs:
    version: '7.0.202'
    packageType: sdk


- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'feed id removed'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Publish"
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '-r win-x64 --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: 'drop'
```